# Blazor HttpClient GetAsync is super slow due to wiping

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, blazor

Using Blazor 0.9.0 I have a simple call to Azure SQL database using HttpClient GetAsync. To return a mere 100 records this can take upwards of 30 seconds. I have experienced and read that due to Blazor "wiping" the abilty to include HttpClientHandlers with the HttpClient is not supported in Blazor - "method is wiped" error returned. Any suggestions on how to improve performance of HttpClient in Blazor? All optimizations of returned columns, size etc have been done. The API call directly in the browser takes 2 seconds so this is specifically a Blazor issue it would appear.

Answer (score 2):

HttpClientHandler is not supported in Blazor . Instead Blazor is using WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler (HttpMessageHandler). I guess you understand why HttpClientHandler is wiped, and the meaning of the message "method is wiped."

Your question about how to improve HttpClient in Blazor had better be directed at the Blazor team in Github.

I believe that HttpClientHandler is supported in server-side Blazor as well as HttpClientFactory...

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for the reply and yes I understand what wiped means. I will try my luck on github. I also understand why the team are wiping - to minimise Blazors footprint :-)